# Defining schema in JsonLoader in PIG

Tags: json, hadoop, schema, apache-pig

I was trying to enter the schema of a dataset while using Pig from a JSON file using the JsonLoader.

The format of the data is as:

```
{
  'cat_a':'some_text',
  'cat_b':{(attribute_name):(attribute_value)}
}
```

I am trying to describe the schema as:

```
LOAD 'filename' USING JsonLoader('cat_a:chararray, cat_b:(attribute_name:chararray,attribute_value:int)');
```

I feel that I'm describing the schema incorrectly for `cat_b`.

Can someone help out in that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your json is of the format

```
{"recipe":"Tacos","ingredients":[{"name":"Beef"},{"name":"Lettuce"},{"name":"Cheese"}]}
```

store the above json in `test.json`

run the below command

```
a = LOAD '/home/abhijit/Desktop/test.json' USING JsonLoader('recipe:chararray,ingredients: {(name:chararray)}');

dump a;
```

you will have output as

```
(Tacos,{(Beef),(Lettuce),(Cheese)},)
```

if your json is like below format

```
{"recipe":"Tacos","ingredients":[{"name":"Beef"},{"name":"Lettuce"},{"name":"Cheese"}],"inventor":{"name":"Alex","age":25}}

a = LOAD '/home/abhijit/Desktop/test.json' USING JsonLoader('recipe:chararray,ingredients: {(name:chararray)},inventor: (name:chararray, age:int)');


dump a;
```

output would be

```
(Tacos,{(Beef),(Lettuce),(Cheese)},(Alex,25))
```

Comment: Did this answer your question...?